# When node.ownerDocument is not window.document?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm looking at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.ownerDocument) and [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#node-ownerDoc) resources to find out what exactly is `ownerDocument` and how it works?

As I tested in any condition `node.ownerDocument == window.document`. So when this property is not `window.document`?

Can you explain it?

Comment: The exact same question occurred to me!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way is if the node was obtained from an iframe or [secondary browser window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open).

Another way is if it's a node from an XML document obtained from an HTTP source [via AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest).

Comment: The first scenario doesn't look right. Inside another window/iframe window object is different.

Comment: @Mohsen: Right, exactly. So if the outer document has a JS variable named `iframe` that points to the iframe, then the outer document will see `iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].ownerDocument === iframe.contentWindow.document`, *not* `iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].ownerDocument === window.document`, because the iframe has a different `window` object (which the outer document refers to as `iframe.contentWindow`). And, similarly with secondary browser windows.

Comment: Can you please explain the second scenario?

Comment: @Jessica: What kind of explanation? Is there something specific about it that you don't understand?

Comment: I've never worked with XML document before. I don't know what it is.

Comment: @Jessica: Ah. Sorry, this isn't really the right forum for that, then. I suggest you just Google *XML*, and then maybe *XML DOM*.